# recursively counting the number of elements in a list that are not v

Tags: python, list, recursion, return

For a list I want to recursively count the number of elements that are not v.

My code so far looks like:

```
def number_not(thelist, v):
"""Returns: number of elements in thelist that are NOT v.

Precondition: thelist is a list of ints
              v is an int"""
total = 0
if thelist is []:
    return total
elif thelist[0] is v:
    print "is v"
    total += 0
    print total
    return number_not(thelist[1:],v)
elif thelist[0] is not v:
    print "is not v"
    total += 1
    print total
    return number_not(thelist[1:],v)

return total
```

It will print the total for each of the individual numbers, but not the final total. For example, for list = [1,2,2,2,1], it will print:

```
is not v
1
is v
0
is v
0
is v
0
is not v
1
```

But then my code gets a traceback(list index out of range) error because it keeps going. How do I make it so that it recurses only for the length of the list and that it return the proper total, which for the example is 2

Comment: What's your base case? What's your recursive case?

Comment: base case is that the list is blank because I have gone through it all. Recursive case 1 is that element is v, recursive case 2 is that element is not v

Comment: If you want to check if list is empty, `if thelist is []:` change this to `if not thelist:`

Comment: `is` is your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the other answers here solve the problem, I don't think they addressed the core issue. The problem is:

```
if thelist is []:
```

Because that conditional statement is not what you think it is. For example:

```
In [2]: [] is []
Out[2]: False
```

`is` tests for identity, not equality as you seem to be assuming in your code. It checks the `id` of an object which is a unique integer which is similar to a memory address in C. Take this example:

```
In [3]: id([])
Out[3]: 140402932955720

In [4]: id([])
Out[4]: 140402923983176
```

Each `[]` is a new object with a unique `id`, so your base condition would never be triggered. For comparison of list instances you should use `==` or `len` (possibly with isinstance if you need to make sure its a list).

As an aside... `is` is appropriate for comparing constants/builtins like:

```
1 is 1
type([]) is list
False is False
```

This is useful when checking something that may be `False` or an `int`. If the variable is `0` and you check `if not var`, `False` and `0` are both Falsey and would both evaluate to `True` so you would want to check `if var is False` and `if var is 0` assuming they had different meaning in your code.

Answer (score 4):

All the code is fine, just the termination condition you have added is not correct,

it should be `if not thelist:`

Change your code to check the empty list, `if thelist is []:` to the above.

Comment: @jam, the  answer you accepted is 10 mins later than mine, and the solution is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your base case is that the list is empty. Then you want to return 0, right?

Your recursive case requires you to split up your list into the first element and the rest. Check the head of the list -- is it not equal to what you're searching for?

```
def counter(needle, haystack):
    if not haystack: 
        return 0

    # Splits the list into the first element and the remaining elements as a list.
    head, *rest = haystack

    if head != needle:
        return counter(needle, rest) + 1
    else:
        return counter(needle, rest)
```

[repl.it](https://repl.it/H0FV/0).

Comment: what is the meaning of the line `head, *rest = haystack`? How does that work?

Comment: I have commented that line. It's unpacking the list. You can see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Basically, it means `head, rest = haystack[0], haystack[1:]`.